# How to pick magento security patches

Tags: magento

I have a webstore running magento 1.9.1 and was prompted with the need for security patching. How can I check which patches from here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ I should download and install? Should I just install all the listed patches?

Answer (score 0):

For the version 1.9.1 you need to take:

SUPEE-5344 (for you is Magento-CE-v1.8.x-1.9.x (0.01 MB))

You may also want this other security patch from October 2014:

SUPEE-1533 (for you is Magento-CE-v1.8.x-1.9.x (0.01 MB))

Install what you need, security patches are the most important.

You can find more information and test if the patches were properly installed on this page:
http://magento.com/security-patch

Comment: But if I get the newest security patch, it won't automatically be applying older security patches automatically? Seems somewhat tedious having to install 5+ security patches pr. site. I can't remember which patches are already installed etc.

Comment: No, patches are independants, SUPEE-1533 updates 2 files, SUPEE-5344 updates 7 others files if you look the patches details (I have Enterprise version so files count may be different)

Comment: @viktor - Magento uses a totally manual patch process. Also keep in mind that since the patches modify Magento Core, they will be removed whenever you upgrade Magento and must be reapplied. I would put an ip address lockdown in the .htaccess file during upgrade to prevent script kiddies from hacking my e-commerce site until I got the patches reapplied. You will have to reapply ALL patches that apply to the upgrade version, starting with the oldest, moving forward.